# Use jquery to fire off my timer

Tags: c#, jquery

I have a timer on my web app called Timer1 and the `enabled = false`. I want to use jquery to fire off my timer. I thought that  `$("Timer1").enableSelection('True');` would work but it doesnt appear to be working.

Any suggestions here?

Thanks guys!

My jquery code:

```
var lastupdate;
        $(function () {
            $.ajaxSetup({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: "{}",
                error: function (a, b, c) {
                    try {
                        var err = (JSON.parse(a.responseText)).Message;
                        alert(err);
                    }
                    catch (ero) {
                        alert(a.responseText);
                    }
                }
            });

            //  updateSettings();
            $("#refreshBaan").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "Default.aspx/refreshBaan",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        $("#lastBaanUpdate").html("");
                        $("#lastBaanUpdate").progressbar({ value: 0 });
                        $("#refreshBaan").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                        //**
                        $(function () {
                            $("Timer1").enableSelection('True');
                            $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: 0 });
                            setTimeout(updateProgress, 200);
                        });
                        function updateProgress() {
                            var progress;
                            progress = $("#progressbar")
    .progressbar("option", "value");
                            if (progress < 100) {
                                $("#progressbar")
        .progressbar("option", "value", progress + 2);
                                setTimeout(updateProgress, 200);


                            }
                        }`
```

My C#:

`<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="17000" 
                ontick="Timer1_Tick" Enabled="False" />`

Comment: Are you able to update your question provide a bit more of the code that you're working with? It's very hard to help out without knowing where you're at.

Comment: I took the liberty to "improve" your question to make it more descriptive and well formatted. I agree with @McHerbie that, as it is, the question is too vague, please give a little more context, the will help us help you.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code Please also try to format it correctly, also please take the time to retag you question if you feel this might be realted to C# or asp (did not do it myself becuase I'm not sure if it applies)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("Timer1")` is not a valid selector. It should be referencing an HTML tag, class or id. 
ex: `$("div")` or `$("#Timer1")` o r `$(".Timer1")`.....and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I really need to see some code... but it looks like this could do the trick:

```
$('#Timer1').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Answer (score 0):

Any tag with the text `runat="server"` in it is a **server-side** tag which cannot be directly manipulated via javascript the way you are attempting to do here.

A timer itself is an AJAX control that's implemented client-side by javascript emitted by the Timer ASP.Net class's Render function, which causes a postback to happen at the specified interval.

By looking at System.Web.Extensions.dll (the assembly the System.Web.UI.Timer class is housed in) in Reflector, it references 'MicrosoftAjaxTimer.js', which is included in the embedded resources section of the DLL. In this file, there appears to be a function named Sys.UI._Timer.set_enabled() which would appear to do what you want.

Keep in mind though you are using the implementation details here directly and these are subject to change at any time by Microsoft. I'd recommend not using JQuery at all, but manipulating the Timer object server-side instead.